# Computing periodogram in r for my time-series data

Tags: r, time-series, frequency, spectrum, spectral-density

I am trying to obtain periodogram of my time-series data.

My data contains time values and intensity values, which are listed in a data frame.

I used spectrum() to obtain periodogram and obtained a power values for each frequency. But I wonder why the function does not require time values. Is there any other function to include time values for periodogram? Or, am I doing something wrong? The time values are numeric.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please read [mcve] to find out how to write a good question.

Comment: There is an implicit assumption in some time series processing software that the samples of intensity (voltage or whatever) have been taken at equal time intervals. If that is not the case then you need a much more careful treatment of computing the periodogram.